# android how to get value from the interface

Tags: java, android

I am getting values in broadcast receiver in `MyFragment` class which extends the interface `DelayTime` as -

```
 if(intent.getAction().equals(BroadcastHelper.DEPARTURE_TIME)){
            Bundle args = intent.getExtras();
            if (args != null) {
                int departure_time = args.getInt("Departure");
                DepartureTime(departure_time);
                }
        }
        else if(intent.getAction().equals(BroadcastHelper.ARRIVAL_TIME)){
            Bundle args = intent.getExtras();
            if (args != null) {
                int arrival_time = args.getInt("Arrival");
                ArrivalTime(arrival_time);
            }
        } 

       @Override
public int ArrivalTime(int arrival_time){
 //what to do here
 Log.d("hi","arrival_time" + arrival_time);
    return arrival_time;
}

@Override
public int DepartureTime(int departure_time){
//what to do here
    return departure_time;
}
```

I have an interface `DelayTime` -

```
public interface DelayTime {
    public int ArrivalTime(int arrival_time);
    public int DepartureTime(int departure_time);
}
```

I need to get the values from MyFragment class in MyOwn Class using the interface. In `MyOwn` class, the implementation which I have done is like -

```
DelayTime delaytime = new MyFragment();
   int arri = delaytime.ArrivalTime(arr);
   Log.d("hi","arrival 0" + arri);
   myAdapter.setArrTime(arri); //Null pointer here
```

The value of `arri` is 0. The logs are like -

```
arrival_time 4500
arrival_time 0
```

Comment: if `DelayTime` is an interface, how can you do `delaytime = new DelayTime();`?

Comment: Sorry..i have edited it. Yeah in my code i am doing delaytime = new MyFragment();

Comment: Your method does nothing, but my eye-debugger cannot detect NPE on the line you pointed. you created an object, and immediately call `object.method()` the method is also very simple, return a primitive int, which is exactly same as the input argument.....

Comment: Ok so what should i do? I am new in Java

Comment: with current codes, I cannot spot the problem.. perhaps your codes were complicated, not easy to paste here, you can run it in debugger, to find out which object is null.

Comment: It is the delaytime object which is null as per the debugger

Comment: Can you insert a check if it is null? If so, then there must be an exception in the Constructor already. Sidenote: I don't get why you just echo the argument values? If you already know them, there is no use for the delaytime thing?

Comment: Yeah I am getting the exception log... the nullpointer exception is Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.myAdapter.setArrTime(int)' on a null object reference...See the edited code

Comment: Then `myAdapter` is null, not `delayTime` ... where do you set/create it?

Comment: Ok..I fixed this. But the value of arri is 0. Why is that

Comment: `public int ArrivalTime(int arrival_time){
 //what to do here
    return arrival_time;
}` Input == Output. If you give it 0 it will return 0.

Comment: Ok I implemented the ArrivalTime(arrival_time); Please see the edited code... Still it is 0

Comment: I do not know what you are missing ... I cannot see where you actually **save** the value. In your Fragment that obviously receives a Broadcast Intent you just write it to a _local_ variable. Then you call what I identified as a non-functional getter. Better then the value is lost. You need to save it to some field in your fragment for example. what is `ArrivalTime` method actually supposed to do? Set or Get?

Comment: It should set a value and i need to get it from MyOwn class. How can i do this programmatically...

Answer (score 0):

Your interface DelayTime should look like this, for standards:

```
public interface Delayer {
    void setArrivalTime(int arrivalTime);
    void setDepartureTime(int departureTime);
}
```

When instantiating your MyOwn class you should pass MyFragment in its constructor and save a reference to it.

```
MyOwn mClass = new MyOwn((DelayTime) mFragment);
```

In the MyOwn class the constructor should be something like:

```
public MyOwn(DelayTime fragmentInterface) {
    this.fragmentInterface = fragmentInterface;
}
```

Have the MyOwn class consume the interface methods:

```
public void setArrivalTime(int arrivalTime) {
    fragmentInterface.setArrivalTime(arrivalTime);
}
```

And use the interface with your MyOwn object like this:

```
mClass.setArrivalTime(yourValue);
```

Also note that fragments are used with the (support) fragment manager and not instantiated directly like that.
I suggest you have a read here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html